# Encoding categorical numeric data to different columns

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I am new to data science and machine learning. I have a column with three values 0,1,2 and I want to encode these 3 values to 3 different columns with prefix predict_.

I have tried get_dummies and label encoder but it didn't workout

```
import pandas as pd
Y = pd.get_dummies(Y,prefix='predict_')

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
```

finally, columns should look like predict_0,predict_1,predict_2

Comment: You can use either `pd.get_dummies` or `LabelEncoder`, but not both of them.

Comment: Hi Quang...I am using one of them but not getting any positive result.

Comment: My DF looks like:                                                               
id                50078 non-null int64
location          50078 non-null object
fault_severity    50078 non-null int64
log_feature       50078 non-null object
volume            50078 non-null int64
event_type        50078 non-null object
resource_type     50078 non-null object
severity_type     50078 non-null object                                                                       I have assigned Y = A['fault_severity'] and tried using one of them but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to pass only the column

```
pd.get_dummies(Y['column_name'],prefix='predict_')
```